Equilateral triangle construction in Poincaré half-plane
Our teacher was using the book Geometry: a metric approach with models by Richard S. Millman and George D. Parker, and gave this problem to solve:

Construct a triangle in the Poincaré plane with all sides equal to
$\text{ln}(2)$. (Hint: Use the fact that, the circle with center
$(0,a)$ and radius $\text{ln}(r)$ with $r>1$ in the Poincaré plane is
equal to the point set $$\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{H} : x^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\left(r+\frac{1}{r}\right)a\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{r}\right)a\right)^2\right\},$$
where $\mathbb{H} = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0\right\}$. Also, see example $6.5.2$ in the book.

I tried to do something similar like the way Euclid constructed equilateral triangle in the Euclidean plane, but while I can draw for instance $$\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{H} : x^2+\left(y-5\right)^2=3^2\right\}$$ and $$\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{H} : x^2+\left(y-8\right)^2=6^2\right\}$$ (both has Poincaré radius $\text{ln}(2)$), I'm unable to construct an equilateral triangle using them. From any of these circles, it's clear that I can construct two sides of $\text{ln}(2)$ length (by taking two line segments along radius), but I'm unable to construct the third side of the triangle.

You might as well begin with two  vertices $A=(0,1)$  and $B=(0,2)$  in your notation. Then, write down an equation for the circle with (Poincare) center $A$  and through point $B.$  Finally  an equation for the circle with Poincare  center $B$  and through point $A.$  That seems the most direct method   given

Meanwhile, given real $C$  and real $D > 0$  the following are unit speed geodesics:  vertical $(C, e^t)$  and semicircle $(C + D \tanh t, D \operatorname{sech} t )$

@WillJagy, thanks so much. Got it.
